# How to show the results of the quiz?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am creating a quiz in Android Studio. My **testActivity.java** has a pager adapter in it which displays 3 fragments(questions). When I press "End" button a new activity called "**Result.java**" starts. It shows how many correct answers I have and did I pass the test. I have another button in my Result activity, which once pressed should open up the same test that the person has just did but with explanations below each question. I also want that the checkboxes that the person have checked during the test would be checked when the results are shown. How can I do that?

By the way, I've noticed that when I press the back button (on my phone) the same test opens with my chosen answers checked. If I could write a code that goes back to previous activity and changes it a bit (adds a text with explanation of the question) it would solve my problem.

**testActivity.java**:

```
public class testActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pager_adapter);
        initialisePaging();
    }

    private  void initialisePaging() {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment2.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment3.class.getName()));
        PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**PagerAdapter.java**:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        return this.fragments.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    public void setFragments(List<Fragment> fragments) {
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }
}
```

**Result.java**:

```
public class Result extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView win_lose, percent, correctAnswers;
    int Ans1, Ans2, Ans3, percentAns;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        calculateResult();
    }

    private void calculateResult() {
        win_lose = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        percent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        correctAnswers = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        final SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        int Ans1 = app_preferences.getInt("answer_value1", 0);
        int Ans2 = app_preferences.getInt("answer_value2", 0);
        int Ans3 = app_preferences.getInt("answer_value3", 0);
        float AnsNum = Ats1+Ats2+Ats3;

        float percentAns = (AnsNum * 100.0f) / 9;
        int correctAns = 0;

        if (Ans1 == 1){correctAns++;};
        if (Ans2 == 1){correctAns++;};
        if (Ans3 == 1){correctAns++;};

        if ( percentAns >= 70 ){
            win_lose.setText("Win");
            percent.setText(String.valueOf(percentAns)+" %");
            percent.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF1DD710"));
            correctAnswers.setText(String.valueOf(correctAns)+"/9");
        } else {
            win_lose.setText("Lose");
            percent.setText(String.valueOf(percentAns)+" %");
            percent.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            correctAnswers.setText(String.valueOf(correctAns)+"/9");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_result, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Architecture should be like this:
TestActivity parent; QuizFragment, ResultFragment and AnswersFragment.

I wouldn't design the Quiz and Answers jobs in one fragment since each fragment should be responsible for one job, i wouldn't expect the ui's to be so similar either.

They should all be managed by TestActivity. You can use a map that holds boolean arrays for each question and pass it to AnswersFragment through TestActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you go for a database that holds the questions, the options, the correct answer, and the test the user do along the time, so it could be loaded from an especific date and it could also have a historic and you could do some statisctic charts on right/wrong answer, average score, etc. So when start the application always start fresh, and if you need to show the results just select the date from the table.